# How to make data, created by app user, persistent in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, persistence

I am trying to make my first app containing persistent data. The goal of the app is to create a price sheet using entities created by the user prior to making a price sheet. There would be a window to create a new item and another to use subset of entities, selected by a user, to create the price sheet. What would be the best way to make the data persistent, so that entities created could be used in later price sheets, and make the app as self contained as possible. I'm sorry if this seems somewhat vague but the options seem numerous but very different and I am not entirely sure how these differences should be handled in the development of an app. (This is also my first question so sorry if it seems unusual in format)
Some options that I have considered are

- SQLlite because it is serverless
- Storage in files using serialization with statements such as ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream because it may be simpler

Which of these options would seem best fit or is there an option that I am missing altogether?

Comment: As it stands your question is too vague and too broad, and is off topic here since this is primarily a Q & A site for programming issues. You are also explicitly seeking opinions, and that is also off topic for SO. Review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I will look elsewhere as the question remains the same for now. Where would you recommend I ask this type of question?

Comment: I have no specific recommendation, but [here are all the Stack Exchange web sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: Ok thank you I will do more research and maybe ask a direct question If i am able to get my question answered elsewhere